# How can I download YouTube captions using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project where I need to download captions (subtitles) from YouTube videos using JavaScript. I've searched for solutions online but haven't found a clear way to accomplish this. Can someone provide guidance on how I can achieve this using JavaScript?

Specifically, I need to:

> - Retrieve the available captions (subtitles) for a given YouTube video.
> - Allow users to select a specific caption language.
> - Download the selected caption in the SubRip (SRT) format.
> - Implement this functionality within a web application using JavaScript.

Any help or examples demonstrating how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>YouTube Caption Downloader</title>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  .container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    text-align: center;
  }

  h1 {
    color: #333;
  }

  input[type="text"] {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  button:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
  }

  #captionsOutput {
    margin-top: 20px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    text-align: left;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>YouTube Caption Downloader</h1>
    <input type="text" id="videoUrl" placeholder="Enter YouTube video URL">
    <button id="downloadBtn">Download Captions</button>
    <div id="captionsOutput"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    async function downloadCaptions(videoId) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=${videoId}&lang=en`);
            const text = await response.text();
            return text;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error downloading captions:', error);
            return null;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('downloadBtn').addEventListener('click', async function() {
        const videoUrl = document.getElementById('videoUrl').value;
        const videoIdMatch = videoUrl.match(/[?&]v=([^&]+)/);
        if (!videoIdMatch) {
            alert('Invalid YouTube video URL');
            return;
        }
        const videoId = videoIdMatch[1];
        const captions = await downloadCaptions(videoId);
        if (!captions) {
            alert('Failed to download captions');
            return;
        }
        document.getElementById('captionsOutput').innerText = captions;
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with CSS? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The css issue I don't think is a problem
  That's just an example of why I'm asking
Obviously, I want to see how YouTube subtitles download

Comment: I think you might want to look into this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73863672/how-can-i-get-captions-of-a-youtube-video-and-display-it-separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73863672/how-can-i-get-captions-of-a-youtube-video-and-display-it-separately)

Comment: this link no one well ask

Comment: "I've searched for solutions online but haven't found a clear way to accomplish this." should be true of every question asked on Stack Overflow and isn't necessary to explicitly say.

Answer (score 1):

If the videos are on a channel you manage, you can use the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) to do this.

- [Retrieve the available captions (subtitles) for a given YouTube video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list).
- [Download the selected caption in the SubRip (SRT) format.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download)

If the videos are on other people’s channels, you may be able to scrape caption details from the page as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77446722/2518285). For example, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCAlv4JIW8Q) contains both English and French subtitles, and in the page source you will find this:

```
...
"captionTracks": [
  {
    "baseUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=uCAlv4JIW8Q&ei=CSnhZfv3G4SF4-EPmLSx0A8&caps=asr&opi=112496729&xoaf=5&hl=en-GB&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1709280121&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,v,ei,caps,opi,xoaf&signature=C54E11DBF4B9E4E86B7F540E34E878489EEF17CD.EEF3F22BCC6257514C771FAE7DBB2D0F6DBFA66F&key=yt8&lang=en",
    "name": {
      "simpleText": "English"
    },
    "vssId": ".en",
    "languageCode": "en",
    "isTranslatable": true,
    "trackName": ""
  },
  {
    "baseUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=uCAlv4JIW8Q&ei=CSnhZfv3G4SF4-EPmLSx0A8&caps=asr&opi=112496729&xoaf=5&hl=en-GB&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1709280121&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,v,ei,caps,opi,xoaf&signature=C54E11DBF4B9E4E86B7F540E34E878489EEF17CD.EEF3F22BCC6257514C771FAE7DBB2D0F6DBFA66F&key=yt8&lang=fr",
    "name": {
      "simpleText": "French"
    },
    "vssId": ".fr",
    "languageCode": "fr",
    "isTranslatable": true,
    "trackName": ""
  }
]
...
```

These URLs do appear to contain an expiry parameter, so they will probably only work for a limited time (a few hours) after you fetch the page. When you fetch from these URLs, you’ll get back an XML response containing the actual captions and timing. Not an SRT file.